# Calling SignalR hub clients from elsewhere in system

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

I've set up a SignalR hub to communicate between the server and client. The hub server side code is stored in a class called Hooking.cs. What I want is to be able to call a method defined in Hooking.cs to allow me to broadcast messages to any connected clients from anywhere in my application. It seems that a new instance of Hooking.cs is created for every client/server call, so I had hoped that I would be able to use something like

```
var hooking = new Hooking();
hooking.Test();
```

with the method Test() defined in Hooking.cs such as

```
public static void Test() {
    Clients.test()
}
```

and with a the client side javascript

```
var hooking = $.connection.hooking;
hooking.test = function() { alert("test worked"); };
$.connection.hub.start()
```

---

Unfortunately it isn't that simple, as Clients is not static, so not accessible from a static method.

Looking through the SignalR source code I came across a method that looked promising, `Hubs.Invoke(string hubName, string method, params object[] args)`, so I would hope I could use something such as `Hubs.Invoke("Hooking", "Test")` but I can't make it work.

Any help with this would be hugely appreciated

Comment: But maybe you can help me ;) Any idea how to perform your js code in your broadcast message for all other clients, and not the originating caller who issued the message? :)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. I've been handling this client side, sending the client id back with the response, and simply not calling the function if the id's match

Answer (score 111):

This is the correct way for SignalR 2.x:

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
context.Clients.All.addMessage(message);
```

Basically, you can use the dependency resolver for the current host to resolve the `IConnectionManager` interface which allows you to get ahold of the context object for a hub.

Further information can be found in the [official documentation](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub).

Answer (score 23):

Hub.GetClients has disappeared in version 0.4.0.

From the [wiki](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs) you can now use:

```
IConnectionManager connectionManager = AspNetHost.DependencyResolver.Resolve<IConnectionManager>();
dynamic clients = connectionManager.GetClients<MyHub>();
```

Comment: And don't forget to add `using SignalR.Infrastructure;`

Answer (score 6):

You can easily use a **hub** by following this 2 step-

1. Instantiating by dependency injection like this-

   ```
   public class ClassName
   {
       ........
       ........
       private IHubContext _hub;

       public BulletinSenderController(IConnectionManager connectionManager)
       {
           _hub = connectionManager.GetHubContext<McpHub>();
           ........
           ........
       }

       ............
       ............
   }
   ```

2.Using the `hub` object like this-

```
_hub.Clients.All.onBulletinSent(bulletinToSend);
```

More can be found **[here](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub)**.

Example code can be found **[in this git repo](https://github.com/abrarjahin/ASP.NetCoreWithSignalR_and_SQLite/blob/master/src/Mcp/Controllers/api/Admin/BulletinController.cs)**.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at how it's done in `Chat.cs` in `SignalR.Samples.Hubs.Chat` from https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR.

I can see in there that static `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`'s are being instantiated at the top, so I imagine they are being maintained persistently too, either with the `Chat` class being a persisted instance (?) or that array being updated somehow.

Check it out, David Fowler would probably be the best on this.

Comment: Yeah I'm using the SignalR samples to try and work this out. The dictionaries are static, so the information persists over multiple instances of the class, that's why I'd hoped I could simply create an instance of Hooking.cs and use that, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

This has changed in .NET Core 2, now you can use dependency injection like this:

```
    private readonly IHubContext<MyHub,IMyHubInterface> _hubContext;

    public MyController(MyHub,IMyHubInterface hubContext)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    public bool SendViaSignalR()
    {
        _hubContext.Clients.All.MyClientSideSignalRMethod(new MyModel());
        return true;
    }
```