# SignalR - Updating clients from Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

Suppose I have a ChatHub class defined along with a Broadcast method.

I know how to broadcast messages to all clients if one of them sends a message, however how can I send a message to all the clients from Global.asax ?

In other words how do I get access to ChatHub from another class?

Here's a basic sample:

```
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
      public void Broadcast(String reqMessage)
      {
        Clients.broadcast(reqMessage);
      }
    }
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Where is your ChatHub class? Can you post some more details ?

Comment: @sandeep, it's a standard hub, any hub. I have added some sample code anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since SignalR 0.5 you can do this using `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext`

#### Sample

```
// get gub context
IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
// broadcast to all clients in this hub
context.Clients.broadcast("Hello World");
```

#### More Information

- [SignalR - Hubs](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs)

Comment: Tnx dude, exactly what I needed! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `ConnectionManager`, as described here: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs.
Btw, your question is most likely a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634255/calling-signalr-hub-clients-from-elsewhere-in-system?rq=1).