# Running infinite loop inside signalR server side method to broadcast data

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

I need to read data from reader continuously and send it to the caller.
I created self hosted window service to act as a signalR. I started infinite loop inside it.

```
public void ReadTags()
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var store = Reader.Read();
            var tags = store.ToArray();
            Clients.Caller.getTagsRead(tags);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("Send", ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

Now, I want to have a control on this method to be able to pause, play or stop this loop next time when a method is invoked. Since Hub creates an instance everytime, this means loop will be running under a different instance.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should run this loop within a `Task` in a separate helper. This helper could be made `Singleton` through an IoC. Your hubs could then receive the helper by Dependency Injection. This way, you would have control on the `Task` instance.

To integrate IoC with SignalR, I liked using [LightInject](http://www.lightinject.net/#signalr).

Finally, [to call clients from outside the hubs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634255/calling-signalr-hub-clients-from-elsewhere-in-system).