# Update ASP MVC database from SignalR hub

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

Is there a way to update fields in the default ASP.NET MVC database directly from a SignalR hub?

As you know, by default on a new MVC template project, Visual Studio creates 3 controllers, `Home`, `Account` and `Manage`. From those 3 it is easy to access the database like this:

```
using (var con = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    var userID = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    var userR = con.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == userID.Id);

    userR.Wins = 0;
    userR.Loses = 0;
    userR.Ties = 0;

    con.SaveChanges();
}
```

where `UserManager` is defined by default like this:

```
private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get
    {
        return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    }
    private set
    {
        _userManager = value;
    }
}
```

I am looking for a way to do something like this in my SignalR Hub.

Comment: I think a question would be, why would you want to? You'd use websockets to update the UI in real time, not update the database. However, you *can* call the hub's context if you really feel so inclined.

Comment: well, based on what I receive in the hub from the client side, i want to update a row in the DB. It is not necessary to do it in the hub, but I do not know where. Can you give me an example of how can I call the hub's context?

To be more specific. I am implementing a chess game, and when it ends, i want to increase the number of wins/draws/loses that the players have.

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10914638/4204026) I believe. Not too sure if it's what you're after though.

Comment: I do not want to call a hub method from elsewhere. I will probably call in the hub a method defined somewhere else, that will update my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see your main issue is to get current user Id inside hub class to update the record in the database. If so you can try to use:

```
string userId = Context.User.Identity.GetUserId<string>();
```

So the final code is going to be:

```
using (var con = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    string userId = Context.User.Identity.GetUserId<string>();
    var userR = con.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == userId);

    userR.Wins = 0;
    userR.Loses = 0;
    userR.Ties = 0;

    con.SaveChanges();
}
```

For sure, it is for case where user's Id is of string type

Comment: Life saver, if i'd have enough reputation i would upvote your response!

Comment: This works now, but it was not available when the question was originally posed, as Context.User.Identity did not exist at that time.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is here: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections

One thing to be aware of is that you have to have signalr authorization configured for this to work.